# In R, Print the country with the highest population density in the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

```
https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Files/1_Indicators%20(Standard)/CSV_FILES/WPP2019_TotalPopulationBySex.csv
```

I want to print the country with the highest population density and all the details of the country given in the dataframe from this database. Also only data of `2020`

How can i do it?

Comment: `df[df$PopDensity==max(df$PopDensity[df$Time==2020]),]` does your work (where `df` is the dataset)?

Comment: i have been need this answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that ok?

```
data=read.csv('https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Files/1_Indicators%20(Standard)/CSV_FILES/WPP2019_TotalPopulationBySex.csv', header = T)
a= unique(data[data$PopDensity==max(data[data$Time==2020,'PopDensity']),'Location'])
print(a)
view(data[data$Location==a&data$Time==2020,])
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working. I think, there is wrong in fread. i need to add that. i import the database from my computer because r studio don't reaction anything this database that because of is very big is , when i write this url

Comment: maybe it's because the `fread` function is coming from dat.table package and it's not loaded on your rstudio. Maybe add `library(data.table)` before (and install the package if necessary

Comment: **Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\file3f00171f10c4', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : unable to create temporary directory ‘C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\file3f00171f10c4’**

i take this warning when i install packeges. i can't install even ggplot2

Comment: That's strange haha does it do such things with all package?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I research about this in all website but i couldn't solution

Comment: did you try uninstall -re install r studio?

Comment: How can we do it without package

Comment: Ok try again I modified my answer using read.csv